# Element not found in the cache - Performing while statement

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, automated-tests

**Hello, I'm trying to perform a while:**

```
        while edit_button.is_displayed():
           self.click_edit_button()
           self.click_delete_trainer_button()
           alert = self.driver.switch_to_alert()
           alert.accept()
           time.sleep(5)
           self.driver.refresh()
```

**but I'm getting this error always:**

```
StaleElementReferenceException: Message: Element not found in the cache - perhaps the page has changed since it was looked up
```

**I read that in python it is necessary to refresh the page when this error occurs, but I tried above and it didn't work**

**Any Idea?**

Answer (score 2):

driver is loosing the edit_button. it may be due to performing the clicks in while loop or may be refresh. The better way here, just use findelement instead of edit_button. like below as per java (you can use any locator, i am just giving line using xpath)

```
 driver.findElement(By.xpath("//path of edit button")).isDisplayed();
```

in  while edit_button.is_displayed(): replace edit_button.is_displayed() with above one in python.

Thanks

Comment: you helped me a lot. Working fine!